# Disabling wrapping link in Svelte

Tags: svelte

I am trying to make a component work as link based on a variable. Is it possible to do that?

So sometimes I want it to work like this:

```
<a href="...">
   <Component />
</a>
```

And sometimes like this:

```
<Component />
```

I need it to work as a link as I need to use `target='_top'` on it. `window.top.location.href=...` does not work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `window.open(href, '_top')`?

Otherwise, what you asked can only be achieved with a `{#if ...}`:

```html
{#if target}
  <a {href} {target}>
    <Component />
  </a>
{:else}
  <Component />
{/if}
```

There are other ways: preventing default click event, preventing click events by CSS, probably more... But I think the first suggestion with `window.open` should workd for you.